# How to change json of default settings in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to add `wordpress` at `intelephense.stubs` in `defaultSettings.json`. But, I couldn't edit it. It showed:

[image]

I am not expert at it. I have added it at `settings.json` like this way:

[image]

Did I do it correctly? Will the entire `intelephense.stubs` be replaced with just that single value? or it will work like this way (which I tried to achieve)?:

```
"intelephense.stubs": [
    "apache",
    "bcmath",
    ..........
    "zlib",
    "wordpress"
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. You've done right.

Just put it in your `settings` and it will overwrite `default settings`.

To be completely sure, copy the `default settings` and paste them in `settings`, adding the ones you want to.

Comment: So, By overwriting it at `settings.json`, it didn't remove other values/settings from `intelephense.stubs` in `defaultSettings.json`, just added new setting (`wordpress`) to the `intelephense.stubs` in `defaultSettings.json`, right?